# Regex quantifiers

Tags: python, regex, reluctant-quantifiers

I'm new to regex and this is stumping me.

In the following example, I want to extract `facebook.com/pages/Dr-Morris-Westfried-Dermatologist/176363502456825?id=176363502456825&amp;sk=info`. I've read up on lazy quantifiers and lookbehinds but I still can't piece together the right regex. I'd expect `facebook.com\/.*?sk=info` to work but it captures too much. Can you guys help?

```
<i class="mrs fbProfileBylineIcon img sp_2p7iu7 sx_96df30"></i></span><span class="fbProfileBylineLabel"><span itemprop="address" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Dr-Morris-Westfried-Dermatologist/176363502456825?sk=page_map" target="_self">7508 15th Avenue, Brooklyn, New York 11228</a></span></span></span><span class="fbProfileBylineFragment"><span class="fbProfileBylineIconContainer"><i class="mrs fbProfileBylineIcon img sp_2p7iu7 sx_9f18df"></i></span><span class="fbProfileBylineLabel"><span itemprop="telephone">(718) 837-9004</span></span></span></div></div></div><a class="title" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Dr-Morris-Westfried-Dermatologist/176363502456825?id=176363502456825&amp;sk=info" aria-label="About Dr. Morris Westfried - Dermatologist">
```

Comment: Search for HTML parsers in python.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2823755

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why your pattern doesn't work:**

You pattern doesn't work because the regex engine try your pattern **from left to right** in the string.

When the regex engine meets the first `facebook.com\/` in the string, and since you use `.*?` after, the regex engine will add to the (possible) match result all the characters (including `"` or `>` or spaces) until it finds `sk=info` (since `.` can match any characters except newlines).

This is the reason why fejese suggests to replace the dot with `[^"]` or aliteralmind suggests to replace it with `[^>]` to make the pattern fail at this position in the string (the first).

Using an html parser is the easiest way if you want to deal with html. However, for a ponctual match or search/replace, note that if an html parser provide security, simplicity, it has a cost in term of performance since you need to load the whole tree of your document for a single task.

Answer (score 4):

As much as I love regex, this is an html parsing task:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = .... # that whole text in the question
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> pred = lambda tag: tag.attrs['href'].endswith('sk=info')
>>> [tag.attrs['href'] for tag in filter(pred, soup.find_all('a'))]
['https://www.facebook.com/pages/Dr-Morris-Westfried-Dermatologist/176363502456825?id=176363502456825&sk=info']
```

Comment: It's probably a better way to proceed, however, this doesn't explain why the pattern doesn't work.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte the question says "I want to extract ..."; and that is what above does. also, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) may be relevant.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte -- many thanks for the regex explanation. I did use BeautifulSoup for a similar task

Answer (score 3):

This works  :)

```
facebook\.com\/[^>]*?sk=info
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/qiByjJZ4DyzBDfHn)

With only `.*` it finds the *first* `facebook.com`, and then continues until the `sk=info`. Since there's another `facebook.com` between, you overlap them.

The unique thing between that you *don't* want is a `>` (or `<`, among other characters), so changing *anything*  to  *anything but a `>`* finds the `facebook.com` ***closest*** to the `sk=info`, as you want.

And yes, using regex for HTML should only be used in basic tasks. Otherwise, use a parser.

Comment: Go to debuggex. It works. The `?` may not be necessary, but it works. It's part of the `[^>]*?` which means zero or more *not `>`* characaters, possesively. It's not a regular `?`, it's the possessive modifier.

Comment: Fair enough; it's a reluctant, not possessive, but kudos for using it. :)

Comment: "Reluctant". Right. Not possessive.

Comment: You were suggesting that the question mark in `?sk=info` is literally part of the url. It isn't. It's `;sk=info`. The question-mark is only to make the regex piece before it (`[^>]*`) reluctant.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have an other facebook.com part. You can restrict the `.*` not to match `"` so it needs to stay within one attribute:

```
facebook\.com\/[^"]*;sk=info
```

Comment: With the literal question mark, it does not work. Read the comments under my answer.